# AJAX and JSON with PDO MySQL

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

I'm trying to get data from an attribute, pass it through ajax into another page, and then insert into mysql.

Right now I have some div elements

```
<div data-categories="[{"name":"Gastropub","pluralName":"Gastropubs"},{"name":"Food","pluralName":"Food"}]">
Name
</div>
```

**Breaking it down**:

```
-----------------------

    [
        {"name":"Gastropub","pluralName":"Gastropubs"},
        {"name":"Food","pluralName":"Food"},
        {"name":"more","pluralName":"more"}
     ]


------------------------
```

data-categories is where I insert a json_encoded array and it pops that out. When I'm trying to do is figure out the best practice of using ajax to get that value maybe with

```
var cats = $('div').data('categories');

$.ajax(function(){
 type:"POST",
 url:"other.php",
 data: "data="+cats,
 success:function(data){
    alert("success");
 }
});
```

**other.php**

Now I'm trying to figure out how to save each value separately into my MySQL in this `other.php`, if I have a table with columns : `name` and `pluralName` (and maybe add more later on) in MySQL data

```
if(isset($_POST['data'])){

   $insert = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO cats(name,pluralName) VALUES(?,?)");

}
```

How do I get those values from a set of json values and insert each value into the proper column? As you can see from the example above, I have more than **1** `name` and `pluralName`

Comment: Are you getting the data in POST??

Comment: @user1566160 ajax should pass the data (json data) into other.php where it should go into the insert syntax. Is that what you're asking?

Answer (score 0):

Making an AJAX call would be like :

```
var data = $("div").attr("data-categories");
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "other.php",
data: "data="+data,
function(data){
    alert("success");
 }
});
```

If you are getting the data in $_POST array then you can probably use :

```
<?php
$str = $_POST['data'];
$data = json_decode($str, true);
//print_r($data);

for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++) {
     $insert = "INSERT INTO cats(name,pluralName) VALUES('".$data[$i]['name']."','"+$data[$i]['pluralName']+"')";
//Insert in database

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

**Jquery**

```
var dataStr = $("div").attr("data-categories");
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "other.php",
    data: {data:dataStr},
    success:function(data){
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

**PHP Code**

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['data']))
{
    $data = $_POST['data'];
    $jsonArray= json_decode($data, true);


    for($i=0;$i<count($jsonArray);$i++) {
        $insert = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO cats(name,pluralName) VALUES('".$jsonArray[$i]['name']."','"+$jsonArray[$i]['pluralName']+"')");
    }
}
?>
```